# Saving data to Cosmos DB from Azure Databricks is very slow

Tags: azure, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-cosmosdb, azure-databricks

I am a beginner with Azure and Databricks and I'm having a difficulty saving a lot of data (ex. 5 GB) from Azure Databricks to Cosmos DB with Spark connector.

**Preface:**
I am facing a problem because I want to populate Cosmos DB container with a lot of rows (ex. 500mil+) for some further testing. Currently I have one container (ex. Container #1) in which I am streaming telemetry data using Stream Analytics. What I want to achieve is taking data from container #1, multiply the data many times, and then save it to a new container #2. I wanted to solve this using Spark connector and Databricks, but the saving is very slow, ex. 1mil rows per 40min, which is not acceptable when I want to save gigabytes of rows to it. Reading from a container on the other hand is blazingly fast, ex. 10s for 1.3mil rows. I disabled indexing on container #2 as I read that this should provide some benefit but it doesn't really make a very noticable difference.
The container #2 is set to 2000 RUs, container #1 to 1000 RUs, both throughputs set to autoscale.

Unfortunately I don't know what I am doing wrong, so any help would be appreciated, even recommendations for other possible ways of solving this (ex. Synapse Analytics, etc.).

P.S.
I read somewhere that I should try first saving to ADLS 2 storage, then read dataframe from it and then to Cosmos DB. It did actually provide an improvement, but again still not near acceptable speeds.

*I apologize in advance for my sloppy english, not my first language.*

### Code

Config

```py
connectionConfigRead = {
  "spark.cosmos.accountEndpoint" : Endpoint,
  "spark.cosmos.accountKey" : Masterkey,
  "spark.cosmos.database" : Database,
  "spark.cosmos.container": Container,
  "spark.cosmos.read.inferSchema.enabled" : "false",
  "spark.cosmos.changeFeed.startFrom" : "Now"
}

connectionConfigWrite = {
  "spark.cosmos.accountEndpoint" : Endpoint,
  "spark.cosmos.accountKey" : Masterkey,
  "spark.cosmos.database" : Database,
  "spark.cosmos.container": Container2,
  "spark.cosmos.changeFeed.startFrom" : "Now"
}
```

Read from a container

```py
customSchema = StructType([
          StructField("iothub-connection-module-id", StringType()),
          StructField("value_type", StringType()),
          StructField("timestamp", DoubleType()),
          StructField("data", StringType()),
          StructField("IoTHub", StringType()),
          StructField("id", StringType()),
          StructField("EventEnqueuedUtcTime", StringType()),
          StructField("sensorId", StringType()),
          StructField("EventProcessedUtcTime", StringType()),
          StructField("PartitionId", IntegerType()),
          StructField("value", DoubleType())
    ])

readDF = (spark.read.schema(customSchema).format("cosmos.oltp").options(**connectionConfigRead).load())
```

Writing to container

```py
readDF.write.mode("append").format("cosmos.oltp").options(**connectionConfigWrite).save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Container #2 does not have enough throughput. Assuming 10 RU/s for each insert, 2000 RU/s can do at most 200 inserts/second. That's 12k/minute or 720k/hour. Since you're only dealing with 5 GB of data and millions of rows, I would scale up to 10000 RU/s autoscale max throughput, that will do 1000/second or 3.6M/hour. Get more information on the Spark connector, [Spark OLTP connector resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-api-sdk-java-spark-v3). Also, make sure Databricks and Cosmos DB are running in the same region. This can be a cause for increased latency.

If you are going to query container #2 you need to index it. Find out which properties you use for your filter predicates, order by, etc. and create the necessary range and composite indexes where needed.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your clarification. I think I understand it better now. I missed the importance of RU before and how many are actually needed for inserting into container.
I had both resources in the same region so this shouldn't be a problem. I will try increasing RU and testing it a bit more. Thank you.

Comment: Sure thing. PS: for services like Cosmos which are resource governed per second, it is recommended to stream data into the service rather than batch process it. The more you can amortize throughput over time, the more efficient and less expensive it is.