# Databricks to cosmos DB uploading data is very slow

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have below code which runs many days, input file has around 9GB of CSV and has millions of rows, I written below code, which executing from 5 days and still not completed,  is there any way we can speed up process uploading data to cosmos DB?

```
import json
import logging
import sys
import azure.cosmos.cosmos_client as cosmos_client
import azure.cosmos.exceptions as exceptions
from azure.cosmos.partition_key import PartitionKey
from typing import Optional


configs = {
    "dev": {
        "file_location": "/FileStore/tables/docs/dpidata_pfile_20050523-20221009.csv",
        "file_type": "csv",
        "infer_schema": False,
        "first_row_is_header": True,
        "delimiter": ",",
        "cdb_url": "https://xyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:443/",
        "db_name": "abc",
        "container_name": "dpi",
        "partition_key": "/dpi"
    },
    "stg": {},
    "prd": {}
}
class LoadToCdb():
    def dpi_data_load(self) -> Optional[bool]:
        try:
            # The applied options are for CSV files. For other file types, these will be ignored.
            df = spark.read.format(self.configs["file_type"]) \
                    .option("inferSchema", self.configs["infer_schema"]) \
                    .option("header", self.configs["first_row_is_header"]) \
                    .option("sep", self.configs["delimiter"]) \
                    .load(self.configs["file_location"])
            df = df.select('dpi', 'Entity Type Code')
            df = (df.withColumnRenamed("dpi","dpi")
                  .withColumnRenamed("Entity Type Code","entity_type_code"))

            df_json = df.toJSON()
            for row in df_json.collect():
                print(row)
                data = json.loads(row)
                data.setdefault('dpi', None)
                data["id"] = data["dpi"]
                
                # this method call will update to cosmos db 
                self.cosmos_db.create_items(data)
        except Exception as e:
            self.log.error("Could not able to load to cosmos db from csv file")
            self.log.error(e)

load_to_cdb = LoadToCdb()
load_to_cdb.dpi_data_load()
```

Comment: it really depends on the Cosmos DB provisioned capacity

Comment: Also, not 100% sure here but, I would recommend using the official CosmosDB Spark Connector instead of collecting the DF and writing each line one by one. Since you collect, this will be written by the driver and not in parallel on the executors.

Comment: I think there are 2 main issues with your code. First, you are loading the whole dataset in memory (df.collect()). Second, you are iterating row by row and indexing to cosmos db accordingly. Supposing it takes 100ms for one document to be extracted, dumped to json and then indexed, it would take you 28 hours for 1M rows (given that you have enough provisioned capacity). You probably need to batch your process.

Comment: also, could be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73853146/saving-data-to-cosmos-db-from-azure-databricks-is-very-slow?rq=1